Memory leak at JavaModuleWrapper.mModuleHolder
I am using react native v0.69 to integrate with an existing native app. I was following integration guide and found a memory leak. I simplified my code base to be able to track it and find a solution but I can not see any way how to fix it.
I also notify this error message coming from react native immediately after I close this activity
unknown:ReactNative com.awesome.app  E  Tried to remove non-existent frame callback

this is LeaksCanary report:
====================================
                                                                                                
HEAP ANALYSIS RESULT
                                                                                                
====================================
                                                                                                        
1 APPLICATION LEAKS
                                                                                                
                                                                                                        
References underlined with "~~~" are likely causes.
                                                                                                
Learn more at https://squ.re/leaks.
                                                                                                
                                                                                                
124939 bytes retained by leaking objects
                                                                                            

Displaying only 1 leak trace out of 3 with the same signature
                                                                                                
Signature: b5cfede934befdd5a3af7ef80b4bdc998d874757
                                                                                                
┬───
                                                                                                
│ GC Root: Global variable in native code
                                                                                                 
│
                                                                                                
├─ com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaModuleWrapper instance
                                                                                                     
│    Leaking: UNKNOWN
                                                                                                
│    Retaining 370 B in 11 objects
                                                                                                
│    ↓ JavaModuleWrapper.mModuleHolder
                                                                                                
│                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                                                                                                
├─ com.facebook.react.bridge.ModuleHolder instance
                                                                                                
│    Leaking: UNKNOWN
                                                                                                
│    Retaining 1.0 kB in 13 objects
                                                                                                
│    ↓ ModuleHolder.mModule
                                                                                                
│                   ~~~~~~~
                                                                                                
├─ com.facebook.react.devsupport.LogBoxModule instance
                                                                                                
│    Leaking: UNKNOWN
                                                                                                
│    Retaining 980 B in 11 objects
                                                                                                
│    mReactApplicationContext instance of 
com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactApplicationContext, wrapping 
android.app.
                                                                                                
│    Application
                                                                                                
│    ↓ LogBoxModule.mSurfaceDelegate
                                                                                                
│                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                                                                                                
├─ com.facebook.react.devsupport.LogBoxDialogSurfaceDelegate 
instance
                                                                                                
│    Leaking: UNKNOWN
                                                                                                
│    Retaining 960 B in 10 objects
                                                                                                
│    ↓ LogBoxDialogSurfaceDelegate.mReactRootView
                                                                                                
│                                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                                                                                                
├─ com.facebook.react.ReactRootView instance
                                                                                                
│    Leaking: YES (View.mContext references a destroyed activity)
                                                                                                
│    Retaining 940 B in 9 objects
                                                                                                
│    View not part of a window view hierarchy
                                                                                                
│    View.mAttachInfo is null (view detached)
                                                                                                
│    View.mWindowAttachCount = 0
                                                                                                
│    mContext instance of com.awesome.activities.MainReactActivity 
 with mDestroyed = true
                                                                                                
│    ↓ View.mContext
                                                                                                
╰→com.awesome.activities.MainReactActivity instance
                                                                                                
Leaking: YES (ObjectWatcher was watching this because 
com.awesome.activities.MainReactActivity
                                                                                                
received Activity#onDestroy() callback and Activity#mDestroyed is 
 true)
                                                                                                
Retaining 41.6 kB in 785 objects
                                                                                                
key = fc60d0e2-e08f-408d-8cda-5f29dec2e0ee
                                                                                                
​watchDurationMillis = 24805
                                                                                                
​retainedDurationMillis = 19800
                                                                                                
​mApplication instance of android.app.Application
                                                                                                ​    mBase instance of android.app.ContextImpl

and this is MainReactActivity.kt
class MainReactActivity : FragmentActivity(), DefaultHardwareBackBtnHandler {
    companion object {
        const val OVERLAY_PERMISSION_REQ_CODE = 1
    }

    private val tag = "Awesome-MRActivity"
    private lateinit var reactRootView: ReactRootView
    private lateinit var reactInstanceManager: ReactInstanceManager


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        SoLoader.init(applicationContext, false)
        reactInstanceManager = buildReactInstanceManager()
        reactRootView = ReactRootView(this)
        reactRootView.startReactApplication(
            reactInstanceManager,
            "PaymentSdk",
            intent.extras
        )
        setContentView(reactRootView)

        checkActivityOverlay()
    }

    private fun buildReactInstanceManager(): ReactInstanceManager =
        ReactInstanceManager.builder()
            .setApplication(application)
            .setCurrentActivity(this)
            .setBundleAssetName("index.android.bundle")
            .setJSMainModulePath("index")
            .addPackages(getModulePackages())
            .setUseDeveloperSupport(BuildConfig.DEBUG)
            .setInitialLifecycleState(LifecycleState.RESUMED)
            .setJavaScriptExecutorFactory(getJavaScriptExecutorFactory())
            .build()


    private fun getJavaScriptExecutorFactory(): JavaScriptExecutorFactory? {
        if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
            return null
        }
        return HermesExecutorFactory()

    }


    private fun getModulePackages(): MutableList<ReactPackage> {
        val packages: MutableList<ReactPackage> = PackageList(application).packages
        return packages
    }

    private fun checkActivityOverlay() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M && BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
            if (!Settings.canDrawOverlays(this)) {
                val intent = Intent(
                    Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION,
                    Uri.parse("package: $packageName")
                )
                startActivityForResult(intent, OVERLAY_PERMISSION_REQ_CODE);
            }
        }
    }
    
    @Deprecated("Deprecated in Java")
    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        if (BuildConfig.DEBUG && requestCode == OVERLAY_PERMISSION_REQ_CODE) {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                if (!Settings.canDrawOverlays(this)) {
                    // SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW permission not granted
                    // TODO LSA: do something when activity can not overlay
                    // TODO: NOTE: IT IS ONLY FOR DEV - double check it in production version
                    Log.i(tag, "onActivityResult: $OVERLAY_PERMISSION_REQ_CODE")
                }
            }
        }
        reactInstanceManager.onActivityResult(this, requestCode, resultCode, data)
    }

    override fun invokeDefaultOnBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed()
    }

    override fun onPause() {
        super.onPause()
        reactInstanceManager.onHostPause(this)
    }

    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        reactInstanceManager.onHostResume(this, this)
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        reactInstanceManager.onHostDestroy(this)
        reactRootView.unmountReactApplication()

    }

    override fun onBackPressed() {

        reactInstanceManager.onBackPressed()
    }

    override fun onKeyUp(keyCode: Int, event: KeyEvent?): Boolean {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU) {
            reactInstanceManager.showDevOptionsDialog()
            return true
        }
        return super.onKeyUp(keyCode, event)
    }
}

and I am opening it in another activity like this:
...
            val mainReactActivityIntent = Intent(context, MainReactActivity::class.java)
            context.startActivity(mainReactActivityIntent)
...


I am also able to track it in Profiler in Android Studio this is detail:

